# Django: block internet connection for testing purposes

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I'd like to make sure my unit tests do not try to connect to Internet, is there a way to raise an exception when they do?

There was a similar question [Python: block network connections for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601828/python-block-network-connections-for-testing-purposes), but the solution proposed there blocks all socket connections, including the database ones, which is not acceptable for Django tests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable a third party API when executing Django unit tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730286/how-can-i-disable-a-third-party-api-when-executing-django-unit-tests)

Comment: @BradBeattie definitely not, that question is about mocking API calls, I just want to make sure I have mocked everything that connects to the Internet and didn't miss a thing (I want the tests to fail otherwise)

Answer (score 5):

Found out a way to do this. You can paste this into your settings.

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:

    # Block Internet access during tests
    import urllib2
    import httplib
    import httplib2

    def _raise_http_error(*args, **kwargs):
        raise urllib2.URLError("I told you not to use the Internet!")

    class AngryHandler(urllib2.BaseHandler):
        handler_order = 1

        def default_open(self, req):
            _raise_http_error()

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(AngryHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    _HTTPHandler = urllib2.HTTPHandler
    urllib2.HTTPHandler = AngryHandler

    httplib.HTTPConnection.connect = lambda self: None
    httplib.HTTPSConnection.connect = lambda self: None
    httplib.HTTPConnection.request = _raise_http_error
    httplib.HTTPSConnection.request = _raise_http_error
    httplib2.Http.request = _raise_http_error
```

Comment: Seems easier to block socket, which I think is upstream of all of these libraries. There's an example here that seems to do something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18601897/64911

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at vcrpy: https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy

The first time you run the test it'll make the external request. Every time after that it'll use a fixture that it stored from the first call. The external requests never get made again, which is what you're trying to accomplish.

Usage is dead simple using a decorator on your unit test:

```
@vcr.use_cassette('fixtures/vcr_cassettes/synopsis.yaml')
def test_iana():
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved').read()
    assert 'Example domains' in response
```

Supports any request made using the following libraries:

- urllib2
- urllib3
- http.client (python3)
- requests (both 1.x and 2.x
  versions)
- httplib2
- boto
- Tornado’s AsyncHTTPClient

Answer (score 2):

[`httpretty`](https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/HTTPretty) solves this problem.

Write a custom test runner where you disable only 3rd party API calls, only in your test suite.

```py
# common/test_runner.py

import httpretty
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner


class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def run_tests(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with httpretty.enabled(allow_net_connect=False):
            return super().run_tests(*args, **kwargs)
```

add this new test runner to your settings

```py
TEST_RUNNER = "common.test_runner.CustomTestRunner"
```

And from now on all external API calls have to be mocked or `httpretty.errors.UnmockedError` will be raised.

Alternatively, if your project uses [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) library, `responses.activate` or `responses.start` should work similarly.